# Issue with redirect_to - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This issue has been driving me nuts for a few days now. It doesn't help that I am newbie to rails and not done any programming for many years!

I have written a little application that allows the user to login with facebook or github and this part works well. However when it comes to the sign out part I get an error - The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

The sign out link does this:-

```
<li class="nav-item pull-right add-space"><%= link_to "Sign out", 'sign_out', method: :delete, class: 'nav-link' %></li>
```

Routes.rb is:-

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 root 'home#index'
 get 'home/profile'
 get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: "sessions#create"
 delete 'sign_out', to: "sessions#destroy", as: 'sign_out'
end
```

And the sessions controller does this:-

```
def destroy
 session[:user_id] = nil
 session[:omniauth] = nil
 redirect_to root_url, alert: "SIGNED OUT"
end
```

It is the last line that is causing me an issue and I have tried numerous things to get it to go back to where it needs to be. When I am signing out the url path in the browser address bar is '/home/profile' and the behaviour I am seeing when the error occurs is that the address bar changes to 'home/sign_out'. In the heroku log I am, seeing the following error:-

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/home/sign_out"):
```

I have tried various different routing options on this line:-

```
redirect_to root_url, alert: "SIGNED OUT"
```

But none have been successful; I thought redirecting to the route URL could be done anywhere and is the behaviour I need as users could sign out from wherever they are in the application.

If I do sign out from the top level of the application (e.g. https:///mysite.com/' it works fine.

Any help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed below code:

```
<li class="nav-item pull-right add-space"><%= link_to "Sign out", 'sign_out', method: :delete, class: 'nav-link' %></li>
```

to

```
<li class="nav-item pull-right add-space"><%= link_to "Sign out", '/sign_out', method: :delete, class: 'nav-link' %></li>
```

Comment: @Dunny accept and vote my answer if it works for you. Thanks

Comment: I think I have now?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
<li class="nav-item pull-right add-space"><%= link_to "Sign out", 'sign_out', method: :delete, class: 'nav-link' %></li>
```

into

```
<li class="nav-item pull-right add-space"><%= link_to "Sign out", sign_out_path, method: :delete, class: 'nav-link' %></li>
```

- `link_to`:

  - **1st argument**: is the link "text" shown on page
  - **2nd argument**: is the `href` value of the rendered `<a>` link

    - Normally, you'll use a variable here instead of a `String`; you used a string: `'sign_out'`.
    - which then renders on the page

      `<a href='sign_out'>Sign Out</a>`

      - and this is relative to your current page. So if you are at `/home` at the moment, then the link will request at `/home/sign_out`; thereby you getting that error.
      - you should use `sign_out_path`, which is a route variable (that you defined in routes.rb`
      - see this line?
        `delete 'sign_out', to: "sessions#destroy", as: 'sign_out'`
      - just append a `_path` or `_url` to the value of `as:`, which in this case is `'sign_out'`, so your route variable that you will use is `sign_out_path`

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
<li class="nav-item pull-right add-space">
   <%= link_to "Sign out", sign_out_path, method: :delete, class: 'nav-link' %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Action `destroy` in your `session_controller` does not perform on `delete` method.

`Delete` method can be used when you have something passing in the link to remove from resources (database) like `DELETE /users/1`

Your action `sign_out` actually performs on `get` method. So change your route:

```
get '/destroy' => 'sessions#destroy'
```

Then the button:

```
<%= link_to 'SIGN OUT', { action: 'destroy', controller: 'sessions' }, class: 'something' %>
```

The action will match the route specified for it, you don't need to pass a `http` method in.